# Get value from database and insert it in a dropdown Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I try to insert data from the database into a dropdown or ChoiceType. The Data comes from two different databases.

Here is my `IndexController`:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request){
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //$city = new Cities();->select("c.id,c.active,c.code,t.text name")
 $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
      ->select("c")
      ->from("DataBaseBundle:Countries","c")
      ->innerJoin("DataBaseBundle:Translationtext","t","WITH","c.translation=t.translation");
 $country = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
 if (!$country){
      throw $this->createNotFoundException("Country not found");
 }
 $form = $this->createForm(CountriesType::class,$country);

 if ($form->isValid()) {
    $user = $form->getData();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}
 return $this->render('ParametersBundle:Countries:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),));
     }
}
```

And my Form called `CountriesType`:

```
<?php

namespace ParametersBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class CountriesType extends AbstractType
{
    private $fooChoices = [
        0 => 'choice naught',
        1 => 'choice one',
        2 => 'choice deuce',
    ];
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('active',CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('countries',TextType::class)
        ->add('countries',ChoiceType::class,['choices' => $this->fooChoices,])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'));
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => array(
                'm' => 'Male',
                'f' => 'Female',
            )
            //'data_class' => 'DataBaseBundle\Entity\Cities'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'country';
    }


}
```

The FooChoices brings data from the code and not from the database.

**EDIT:** And my Entity (The traslation is in another database called Traslations)

```
    <?php

namespace DataBaseBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Countries
 */
class Countries
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $active = '1';

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $code2;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $code3;

/**
 * @var \DataBaseBundle\Entity\Continents
 */
private $continents;

/**
 * @var \DataBaseBundle\Entity\Translation
 */
private $translation;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set active
 *
 * @param integer $active
 *
 * @return Countries
 */
public function setActive($active)
{
    $this->active = $active;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get active
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getActive()
{
    return $this->active;
}

/**
 * Set code2
 *
 * @param string $code2
 *
 * @return Countries
 */
public function setCode2($code2)
{
    $this->code2 = $code2;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get code2
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCode2()
{
    return $this->code2;
}

/**
 * Set code3
 *
 * @param string $code3
 *
 * @return Countries
 */
public function setCode3($code3)
{
    $this->code3 = $code3;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get code3
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCode3()
{
    return $this->code3;
}

/**
 * Set continents
 *
 * @param \DataBaseBundle\Entity\Continents $continents
 *
 * @return Countries
 */
public function setContinents(\DataBaseBundle\Entity\Continents $continents = null)
{
    $this->continents = $continents;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get continents
 *
 * @return \DataBaseBundle\Entity\Continents
 */
public function getContinents()
{
    return $this->continents;
}

/**
 * Set translation
 *
 * @param \DataBaseBundle\Entity\Translation $translation
 *
 * @return Countries
 */
public function setTranslation(\DataBaseBundle\Entity\Translation $translation = null)
{
    $this->translation = $translation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get translation
 *
 * @return \DataBaseBundle\Entity\Translation
 */
public function getTranslation()
{


       return $this->translation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look to my solution and let me know if you face some problems

Comment: I made some enhancment take a look no need to use ArrayCollection

Comment: Happy to help y.

Comment: Could you @Pablo Malynovytch please accept my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstable you need to build an  *array*, from the returned query , contains the countries names:

```
//IndexController
$country = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    $data= array();
     foreach ( $country as $c) {
        array_push($data,$c->getTranslation());

    }
    $form = $this->createForm(CountriesType::class,$data);
```

Then you need to pass the *options* array argument into the  *add* statment.
Just replace this line :

```
     //CountriesType
   ->add('countries',ChoiceType::class,['choices' => $this->fooChoices,])
```

with this one :

```
 ->add('countries',ChoiceType::class,array('choices' => $options))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my Entity has not getName as a function and I tried to put getID but nothing...Only appears unknown information like label_format,by_reference,extra_fields_message,csrf_token_manager

Comment: Any idea?I try but nothing

Comment: You said "The FooChoices brings data from the code and not from the database" can you tell me what's the data name you wana bring from the database ?(the column name or the attribute name from the entity)

Comment: I have in the Database Translationtext the column Text (this i want to print) and Countries Table...There I only have the ID of the translation and the ID (that I want to request as value in the select)...Tell me if u understan or u need the entity of the translation.

Comment: The query its correct because I can print it as HTML.

Comment: so this mean that translation column contain the countries names ?
i'm trying to guess where i found the countries names from the database.
If yes just change $c->getName() whith $c->getTranslation()

Comment: Yes...the same as the first comment: "Only appears unknown information like label_format,by_reference,extra_fields_message,csrf_token_ma‌​nager"

Comment: Bro i really need to see the code and the execution in front of me , can you contact me on my facebook : fb.com/la7med

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144501/discussion-between-bhs-and-pablo-malynovytch).

Comment: OK..go to chat please! Thanks

Comment: Thank! I have do it!...[CLOSED]

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
    namespace ParametersBundle\Form;       
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

    class CountriesType extends AbstractType
    {

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
            $fooChoices = $options['choices'];

            $builder->add('active',CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('countries',TextType::class)
            ->add('countries',ChoiceType::class,['choices' => $fooChoices,])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'));
        }
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'choices' => null,
                )
                //'data_class' => 'DataBaseBundle\Entity\Cities'
            ));
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
            return 'country';
        }


    }
```

And finally, to build the form into the *Controller* :

```
$form = $this->createForm(CountriesType::class,array('choices' => $country));
```

Comment: Sorry but nothing...my html :<select id="country_countries" name="country[countries]"></select>